# fetch rows dynamically from one table and get values from other table sum it up and insert into target table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, optimization

`x` table has columns(`Agency`,`datac`)
`Y` table has columns(`Agencyname`,`total`)
EXAMPLE

```
Agency | datac
NET    | 100 
GOO    | 300 
NET    | 100 
GOO    | 100 

Agencyname | total
NET        |  
GOO        |
```

first customer adds `Agencyname` then it gets update on table `Y` 
From a dropdown menu in html i have made user to either choose `NET` OR `GOO` but what i want is how many values they may enter in table `X`. 

i want their `total sum` to be inserted into table `Y`. so that my expected output looks like this

```
Agencyname | total
NET        | 200
GOO        | 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way is probably an update with a subquery;

```
UPDATE TableY
SET total = (SELECT SUM(datac) FROM TableX WHERE Agency=AgencyName)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2860/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Y
SET Y.total = X.Total
FROM TABLE_Y Y INNER JOIN 
                  (
                    SELECT Agency, SUM(datac) AS Total
                    FROM TABLE_X 
                    GROUP BY Agency
                  ) X
ON Y.Agencyname = X.Agency
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE TEST`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43eb78/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT agency, SUM(datac) FROM x GROUP BY agency
```

You want to combine this with `INSERT INTO`.

Although I do not see much sense in caching this easy-to-compute values...

Comment: Hii frnd i have executed above query it works but how to insert those values to table Y can you help me out please